# How to trigger onclick dynamically with many elements on the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, onclick

I have few values retrieved from DB. I need to update the product information using one on click function. Every click only the first product information is being populated. I want to load dynamically. Can I do it with onclick function? please help me.

```
    <tr>
<td id="product_name">Cheese</td>
<td id="product_id">12547777</td>
<td id="scheduled_time">04:00 PM</td>
<td id="distributor_name">Elle Nutrients</td>
<td id="order_status">Complete</td>
<td><i class="icon text-info fa fa-pencil" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="addproduct(this.id)"></i></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="product_name">Butter</td>
<td id="product_id">12577788</td>
<td id="scheduled_time">05:00 PM</td>
<td id="distributor_name">Oetker</td>
<td id="order_status">Waiting</td>
<td><i class="icon text-info fa fa-pencil" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="addproduct(this.id)"></i></td>
</tr>
```

My script:

```
function addproduct(){

    var productname = this.$("#product_name").text();
    var productid = this.$("#product_id").text();
    var name = document.getElementById('new_productname');
    name.value = productname;
    var newid = document.getElementById('new_productid');
    newid.value = productid;
}
```

Comment: IDs have to be unique, use classes for repeating elements.

Comment: `this.$("#product_name")` is not valid syntax. I think you mean `$(element).closest("tr").find("#product_name")`

Comment: If I add your piece of code, it stopped working completely.

Comment: I know that was little bad coding, that's why I posted here so someone proficient in javascript or jquery will help to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

First, you're passing an argument to the function, but you don't have a parameter in the function definition.

Second, your syntax for DOM navigation is all wrong. Use methods like `.closest()` and `.find()` to navigate.

Third, IDs have to be unique. Use classes for repeated elements.

```js
function addproduct(element) {
  var row = $(element).closest("tr");
  var productname = row.find(".product_name").text();
  var productid = row.find(".product_id").text();
  $("#new_productname").val(productname);
  $("#new_productid").val(productid);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
  <td class="product_name">Cheese</td>
  <td class="product_id">12547777</td>
  <td class="scheduled_time">04:00 PM</td>
  <td class="distributor_name">Elle Nutrients</td>
  <td class="order_status">Complete</td>
  <td><i class="icon text-info fa fa-pencil" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="addproduct(this)">X</i></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="product_name">Butter</td>
  <td class="product_id">12577788</td>
  <td class="scheduled_time">05:00 PM</td>
  <td class="distributor_name">Oetker</td>
  <td class="order_status">Waiting</td>
  <td><i class="icon text-info fa fa-pencil" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="addproduct(this)">X</i></td>
</tr>
</table>
New name: <input id="new_productname">
<br>
New ID: <input id="new_productid">
```